# Algebraic Topology exercise on Poincare Duality

Tags: algebraic-topology

There is an exercise in Algebraic Topology that says the following :

> Let $M,N$ be closed , connected orientable manifolds of dimension $n$. Show that if $f:M\rightarrow N$ is such that $f_* : H_n(M)\rightarrow H_n(N)$ is non-zero, then $\dim_{\mathbb{Q}} H_k(M;\mathbb{Q})\geq \dim_{\mathbb{Q}}H_k(N;\mathbb{Q})$ for all $k$.

Now I was able to do this exercise, but I was wondering if this generalizes for any field or is there a known counterexample ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unclear what you mean by "is non-zero", because you don't specify the coefficients there. Let's say your $f_*$ is multiplication by $k$ --- that is $f$ has degree k.

Then your result holds for any field F whose characteristic is coprime to k. This is equivalent to saying that $f_*$ is nonzero on $H_n(-;F)$, but usually you calculate the degree by thinking with integral coefficients.

The proof uses that the intersection pairing is unimodular. This means that over any field, if $x \in H^j(N;F)$ is nonzero, there is some element $y \in H^{n-j}(N; F)$ with $xy = 1 \in F \cong H^n(N;F)$.

Then you can prove that $f^*$ is injective. Over a field $f^*$ is dual to $f_*$ and it follows that $f_*$ is surjective as desired.